# How to display the nearest cities using any API?

Tags: php, api, module

I am developing a Travel website.Presently I am doing the destination module.Here I am listing the nearest cities for any place.
First I will insert all the cities in india into my database.If any one select a particular city,then it should display the nearest cities for the selected city.
You can check the similar functionality here **http://www.mustseeindia.com**

For displaying the nearest cities for any place,Is it possible by using any **API's**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite simple using Google Geocoding and Geometry APIs:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Comment: @leftclickben..Thanks for your response..I want to list the nearest cities one by one..I dont want to show the nearest cities in google map..Is there any method to list the nearest cities?

Comment: When did I say anything about displaying on Google Maps?  I said use the Geocoding and Geometry APIs...  Did you read the links?